# Alternative using hash for storing passwords in Database

Tags: algorithm, security, postgresql, hash, passwords

I need some mechanizm of safe storing passwords in database with inverse algorithm(that's why hashing unfortunately does not fit).
Does anyone know about such algorythms and how to realize one of them in PostgreSQL?
May be any secret-key cryptography?

Comment: Care to explain why you need to reverse the cryptography?

Comment: one advantage of (smart)hashing is one can't recover password. You can only change it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I would strongly advice you to be very cautious about what you are trying to accomplish here; yes a secret-key cryptography would be a good solution to your problem.

Fortunately, PostgreSQL provides support for encryption and it can be achieved as easily as this:

```
Select encrypt (info_to_encrypted, key, algorithm_name);
```

The topic might be lengthy and thus I'd direct you to check these excellent slides:
[Encrypted PostgreSQL](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CFUQFjAD&url=http://www.hagander.net/talks/Encrypted%2520PostgreSQL.pdf&ei=qaswUcGAA8z04QTGz4BY&usg=AFQjCNHgxnf_1lxTNhGjhhdfKsZtnf1KnA&sig2=L5dt4anEtGKD0FDSPSbL-w&bvm=bv.43148975,d.bGE&cad=rja)

Also please read [this very good stackexchange question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24370/how-to-use-aes-encryption-in-postgresql) before you proceed with what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no way of storing a password safely with an invertible algorithm, because it is the idea of these algorithms is that everything they encrypt can be decrypted and therefore they will always be unsafe.